# How can I run a search job periodically in Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to visualize the browser statistics of our app hosted in Azure.

For that I'm using the nginx logs and run an Azure Log Analytics query like this:

```
ContainerLog
| where LogEntrySource == "stdout" and LogEntry has "nginx"
| extend logEntry=parse_json(LogEntry)
| extend userAgent=parse_user_agent(logEntry.nginx.http_user_agent, "browser")
| extend browser=parse_json(userAgent)
| summarize count=count() by tostring(browser.Browser.Family)
| sort by ['count']
| render piechart with (legend=hidden)
```

Then I'm getting this diagram, which is exactly what I want:

[image]

But the query is very very slow. If I set the time range to more than just the last few hours it takes several minutes or doesn't work at all.

My solution is to use a [search job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/search-jobs) like this:

```
ContainerLog
| where LogEntrySource == "stdout" and LogEntry has "nginx"
| extend d=parse_json(LogEntry)
| extend user_agent=parse_user_agent(d.nginx.http_user_agent, "browser")
| extend browser=parse_json(user_agent)
```

It creates a new table BrowserStats_SRCH on which I can do this search query:

```
BrowserStats_SRCH
| summarize count=count() by tostring(browser.Browser.Family)
| sort by ['count']
| render piechart with (legend=hidden)
```

This is much faster now and only takes some seconds.

But my problem is, how can I keep this up-to-date? Preferably this search job would run once a day automatically and refreshed the BrowserStats_SRCH table so that new queries on that table run always on the most recent logs. Is this possible? Right now I can't even trigger the search job manually again, because then I get the error "A destination table with this name already exists".

In the end I would like to have a deeplink to the pie chart with the browser stats without the need to do any further click. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my problem is, how can I keep this up-to-date? Preferably this search job would run once a day automatically and refreshed the BrowserStats_SRCH table so that new queries on that table run always on the most recent logs. Is this possible?

You can [leverage the api to create a search job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/search-jobs?tabs=api-1%2Capi-2#run-a-search-job). Then use [a timer triggered azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) or logic app to call that api on a schedule.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000/resourcegroups/testRG/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/testWS/tables/Syslog_suspected_SRCH?api-version=2021-12-01-preview
```

with a request body containing the query

```json
{
    "properties": { 
        "searchResults": {
                "query": "Syslog | where * has 'suspected.exe'",
                "limit": 1000,
                "startSearchTime": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "endSearchTime": "2020-01-31T00:00:00Z"
            }
    }
}
```

Or you can use the Azure CLI:

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace table search-job create --subscription ContosoSID --resource-group ContosoRG  --workspace-name ContosoWorkspace --name HeartbeatByIp_SRCH --search-query 'Heartbeat | where ComputerIP has "00.000.00.000"' --limit 1500 --start-search-time "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" --end-search-time "2022-01-08T00:00:00.000Z" --no-wait
```

> Right now I can't even trigger the search job manually again, because then I get the error "A destination table with this name already exists".

Before you start the job as described above, remove the old result table using [an api call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/tables/delete?tabs=HTTP):

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/tables/{tableName}?api-version=2021-12-01-preview
```

Optionally, you could check the status of the job using [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/search-jobs?tabs=api-1%2Capi-2#get-search-job-status-and-details) before you delete it to make sure it is not `InProgress` or `Deleting`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks very promising, but I'm still struggeling a bit. I've managed to delete the table (or get its current status) via the Javascript Azure SDK like in this [example request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/tables/delete?tabs=JavaScript#tablesget). The SDK is also handling the authorization via managed identities that I created. But I don't see how I can run a search job via the SDK. Is this also possible? Or do I have to do this with plain Node.js and handle the authorization by myself?

Comment: @ush189 well there are 2 options to run a search job, either using an http request as shown in my answer or use the [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/search-jobs?tabs=cli-1%2Capi-2#run-a-search-job). There is no Azure SDK than can do this so yes, you need to handle authorization  yourself. Using the Azure CLI might be easier.